# Cinema-history tag seems to be attracting trivia

Tags: discussion, tags, policy

Since [trivia is banned](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) why do we allow questions like "What was the first/most X", "Who was the first/most X to do X" on the cinema-history tag? It seems to me that those will be questions will invariably be trivia in nature.

A recent popular example is this question about the "[First Movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/42179/26325)." That is pure trivia, and would easily fit on any trivia game/show.

[Ankit Sharma](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1190/ankit-sharma) stated in the comments they interpret [cinema-history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema-history) questions as ones that:

> Fall under application or analysis rather than plain trivia.

That seems like a good litmus test to me.

Comment: Trivia is crap that can be answered on IMDb like "Who played ___ in ____ movie?" History of cinema is not trivia.

Comment: Doesn't cinema history fall under application or analysis rather then plain trivia.

Comment: @AnkitSharma [This question about box office take](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35208/26325) is the only one about analysis that I see except maybe Sweariest movie...

Comment: @AnkitSharma That is a really useful distinction I think. That makes sense to me how it is distinct from trivia. It just seems to me that the bulk of the questions this tag attracts are in the form of "What/who is/was the first to do X".  That feels like trivia.  Application/analysis feels useful and non-trivia.